# Relationship between energy density and energy flux

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, density

I'm presently working on obtaining conservation laws via symmetries. These conservation laws are written as 2-element vectors where each element is the energy density and energy flux. To proceed in my research I must establish a direct relationship between energy density and energy flux, as it relates to the conservation laws. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the density $\rho$ of some quantity $Q$ and its flux $\mathbf j$ is always in the form of a continuity equation,
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\mathbf j=S,
$$
where $S$ is a source term for $Q$, equal to the amount of $Q$ that appears per unit volume per unit time at each position. If $Q$ is conserved and you've included all the relevant forms of $Q$ inside $\rho$ and $\mathbf j$, then $S$ will vanish. This applies, for example, to the energy density of a closed dynamical system, or to any component of momentum or angular momentum.

Comment: Thanks Emilio. If I understand your answer very well, if Q is conserved  (i.e. S=0) then 

∂ρ/∂t = -∇⋅j

Is it that straight-forward?

Comment: Yes, it is that straightforward, though you do need to ensure that you have indeed accounted for all relevant forms of energy.